# to find the implementation of execv() from linux kernel 3.2

Tags: execv

How to find the implementation of execv() (including its path) and where is it defined in the linux kernel 3.2?

I am trying to find its implementation and write a redirection code in this file which redirects to my custom system call.

Comment: execv is not part of the Linux kernel, it's defined in libc.

Comment: you also might want to consider using `LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c